# converting rows to columns to create a matrix

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, tapply

I have data in the following form and i would like to create a matrix from this data.

```
 B<- c('nancy','bill','bob','badri','bill')
 c<- c('martial-arts','dance','sports','judo','judo')

  df<- data.frame(B,C)
```

I want to create a matrix who belongs to which group and with user as row.names. Can anyone have any suggestions?

```
    user martial-arts dance sports judo 
    nancy      1         0      0    0
    bill       0         1      0    1
    bob        0         0      1    0
    badri      0         0      0    1
```

Comment: Looks like `with(df, as.matrix(table(B, C)))` might do it.

Comment: Or `reshape2::dcast(df, B ~ C, fun = length)`, which is probably better for large data but returns a data frame.

Comment: `xtabs(count ~ ., transform(df, count=1) )` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
x <- c('nancy','bill','bob','badri','bill')
y <- c('martial-arts','dance','sports','judo','judo')

x0 <- unique(x); y0 <- unique(y)
mat <- matrix(0L, length(x0), length(y0), dimnames = list(x0, y0))
mat[cbind(match(x, x0), match(y, y0))] <- 1L

#      martial-arts dance sports judo
#nancy            1     0      0    0
#bill             0     1      0    1
#bob              0     0      1    0
#badri            0     0      0    1
```

I have used matrix indexing:

- `match(x, x0)` gives row index;
- `match(y, y0)` gives column index;
- `cbind(match(x, x0), match(y, y0))` gives matrix index where 1 is.

---

If you have an idea that the resulting matrix has a lot more zeros than ones, you may construct a sparse matrix:

```
library(Matrix)
sparseMatrix(i = match(x, x0), j = match(y, y0), x = 1, dimnames = list(x0, y0))

#4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#      martial-arts dance sports judo
#nancy            1     .      .    .
#bill             .     1      .    1
#bob              .     .      1    .
#badri            .     .      .    1
```

---

[@thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496803/thelatemail)'s alternative:

```
## coding to factor with desired order of levels is necessary
x <- factor(x, levels = x0)
y <- factor(y, levels = y0)

## dense matrix
xtabs(~ x + y)

#       y
#x       martial-arts dance sports judo
#  nancy            1     0      0    0
#  bill             0     1      0    1
#  bob              0     0      1    0
#  badri            0     0      0    1

## sparse matrix
xtabs(~ x + y, sparse = TRUE)

#4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#      martial-arts dance sports judo
#nancy            1     .      .    .
#bill             .     1      .    1
#bob              .     .      1    .
#badri            .     .      .    1
```

Comment: can we create the matrix with id values for network analysis? Like u1, u2, u3 for users and g1,g2,g3 for groups? Thanks so much!

Comment: Yep I did it :)